# What does capturing the mouse mean in reference to the GetCapture() function?

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-c++, mouseevent

I'm reading about the GetCapture() function , which is part of the mfc.
I'm still unclear as to what it does, as well as what it means to capture the mouse , as it says here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dxa5eaaa(v=vs.80).aspx

in my book it's used in this way:

```
 void CSketcherView::OnLButtonUp(UINY nFlags, CPoint point)
 {
   if(this == GetCapture())
       ReleaseCapture();                    // Stop capturing mouse messages

   // ... add information to document
}
```

So what does GetCapture() return? and what does "capturing" the mouse mean?

Answer (score 3):

As a concrete example for the purpose of mouse capture:

Take a window with two pushbuttons.  Click on one of them and keep the mouse button held down.  Now drag the mouse cursor over to the second pushbutton and release the mouse button.  The first pushbutton will receive a `WM_LBUTTONUP` message, but the second won't, even though the mouse cursor is on top of it.

When that first pushbutton received the `WM_LBUTTONDOWN` message, it *captured* the mouse.  While a window is capturing the mouse, it guarantees that it will receive all subsequent mouse events (particularly the `WM_LBUTTONUP` message), even if the mouse has been dragged outside of its window bounds.  This is important so that it can match button-down to button-up messages and maintain proper state.  It's also important for usability (if you click on one button and accidentally move away to another button, you neither want to trigger the first nor the second button).

Comment: thanks, but do you mean that even if the cursor is outside the window, the window still receives messages? I'm still not very clear about it.

Comment: @Ghost: Even if the cursor is outside the window *and* if that window has captured the mouse, yes, the window will still receive a `WM_LBUTTONUP` message.  You also might be interested in: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645601%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#_win32_Mouse_Capture

Answer (score 2):

Capturing the mouse usually means you will stil get Mouse events even when the mouse cursor position is outside the bounds of your window

The `GetCapture` function simply returns the current window that has the mouse capture.

Comment: So u're saying that the GetCapture() function returns the window in which the cursor is not there?

Comment: It returns the window which will received mouse move events

Comment: but doesn't windows send the window messages such as WM_LBUTTONUP and WM_MOUSEMOVE even if we don't specify using SetCapture() or GetCapture() ?